# Shell Script to find newly added pods in kubernetes on day basics

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, kubernetes

I want a shell scripts for find which kubernetes pods is newly added to the cluster. Include the pod name,date&Time and Namespace.

I have tried with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

p=50            #total pods count

pcount=`kubectl get pods |wc -l`

###Addition check
if [ $ncount -gt $n ]
then

    ####pods variable have all pods name.
    pods=`kubectl get pods|awk '{print $1}'|awk '{if(NR>1)print}'| xargs`

    ###start variable have all dates pods created

    start=`kubectl describe pod $pods |grep "Start Time"|awk '{print $3 $4 $5 $6}'`

    ###max variable have total number of pods
    max=`kubectl get pods |awk '{if(NR>1)print}'| wc -l`

    dt=`date +%a,%d%b%Y`

    array=( $start )

    i=0
    while [  $i -lt $max ];
    do
        #    echo "inside loop ${array[$i]}"

        if [[ "$dt" == "${array[$i]}" ]];then
             dat=`date "+%a, %d %b %Y"`
             name=`kubectl describe pod $pods |grep -v SecretName: |echo "$dat" |egrep 'Name|Start Time'`

             printf "\n"
             echo "Newly Added pods are: $name"
        fi
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    done
fi
```

The script working almost fine. But I need only today's created pods,the scripts showing all pods Name, Start Time and Namespace.

Please help.

Comment: There are some obvious bugs here, like `grep | echo` doesn't do anything useful. Maybe try http://shellcheck.net/ to get at least some of them sorted out.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show sample output so we can figure out where you expect the date to be picked up and what it looks like?

Comment: Output would be something like this:

Newly added pods are:
`
Name:           nginx-58432966c-ssjqx
Namespace:      steven_lung
Start Time:     Sat, 16 Jun 2018 05:11:27 +0000
`

Comment: No I mean what does the raw output from `kubectl` look like in this scenario? And please [edit] your question with this detail -- like you just discovered, supplying this in a comment is just not working (and your question should be self-contained anyway).

Comment: **Issue fixed. Changed code like below:**

if [[ "$dt" == "${array[$i]}" ]];then
        dat=`date "+%a, %d %b %Y"`
        #name=`kubectl describe pod $pods |grep -v SecretName: |grep -B 1 '$dat'`
        kubectl describe pod $pods |grep -v SecretName: |grep -E "Name:|Start Time:" > pod.txt |cat pod.txt | grep -B 1 "$dat" > pod1.txt
    fi
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))

Answer (score 1):

Your script has numerous issues and inefficiencies.  Repeatedly calling a somewhat heavy command like `kubectl` should be avoided; try to rearrange things so that you only run it once, and extract the information you need from it.  I'm vaguely guessing you actually want something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store pod names in an array  
pods=($(kubectl get pods |
    awk 'NR>1 { printf sep $1; sep=" "}'))
if [ ${#pods[@]} -gt $n ]; then  # $n is still undefined!
    for pod in "${pods[@]}"; do
        kubectl describe pod "$pod" |
        awk -v dt="$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y")" '
            /SecretName:/ { next }
            /Name:/ { name=$NF }
            /Start Time:/ { t=$3 $4 $5 $6;
                if (t==dt) print name
                name="" }'
    done
fi
```

Once you run Awk anyway, it makes sense to refactor as much as the processing into Awk; it can do everything `grep` and `cut` and `sed` can do, and much more.  Notice also how we use the `$(command)` command substitution syntax in preference over the obsolescent legacy `` `command` `` syntax.

`kubectl` with `-o=json` would probably be a lot easier and more straightforward to process programmatically so you should really look into that. I don't have a Kubernetes cluster to play around with so I'm only pointing this out as a direction for further improvement.

Comment: I will readily admit that I had to guess several things about what your script is supposed to do and what the output from `kubectl` is expected to look like. If nothing else, this should hopefully at least guide you towards simplifying your script, and perhaps, asking better questions in the future.

Comment: I have tried with this scripts, but its showing the following errors. Can you please fix this:

line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
line 5: `pods=(kubectl get pods |'
line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
line 6: `    awk 'NR>1 { printf sep $1; sep=" "}')'

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy typing; try now. Like I wrote earlier, I don't have access to `kubectl`, so I have no way to test this code.